# Databinding to a Dynamic property

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

In my application I have the following which works fine.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,27.5">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

But now I want to bind a different sort of `Items` which have no `Name` property, but a `Title` property.

I've tried the following:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding {Binding MyDynamicProperty}}" />
```

So that I could set `MyDynamicProperty` in code to either `Name` or `Title`, but it crashes pretty soon.

Now I'm not really sure how I should go about this so that I can bind several different `Items` collections with a different property for the text to display.

Comment: `But now I want to bind a different sort of Items` - use [DataType-specific DataTemplates](http://www.codemag.com/Article/0907111).

Comment: @HighCore Sorry, i forgot to mention I'm doing this in a windows app. I've quickly checked, but there don't seem to be `DataTypes` available in my `DataTemplate`

Comment: Could always throw it a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br209471)